# Deploy ruby on rails application built on windows

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm looking on ways to deploy a ruby on rails 4 app built on windows 7 box. I'm looking to use Heroku at the moment.

Can you please provide any pointers regarding heroku or any other easier and cheaper deployment options available out there..
Any issues That I may face due to the difference in OS in the dev environment (windows) and the deployment environment (linux on heroku)?

This is my first professional app, so any pointers will be helpful for now and also for future applications that I may work on.

Also what is the more preferred OS for ruby on rails development ?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't face any issues with deployment on Heroku. Heroku is the easiest option out there (albeit one of the priciest once you're off the free tier)

What's more likely to happen on Windows is that you'll find it hard to build certain gems for development, and cutting edge releases will probably not work well.

Much better to pick up a Linux distro for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out [bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/) , which is also free for small projects.  I know Heroku is not particularly windows friendly, not sure if bluemix is any better in that reguard, but it is extremely easy to deploy to.

Answer (score 0):

`Heroku` has set of tools called `heroku toolbelt`, that makes easy to deploy apps to `heroku`. you can download `heroku tool belt for windows` from [here](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/windows)

Generally you should be able to port any rails app you develop in windows to Linux/Mac, how ever since the `ruby/rails` community is largely built around Linux/Mac, responses/options to your issues regarding the rails apps will be low. and there are some gems which doesn't work on windows at all. So its best to move to either Mac/Linux if you are planing to continue on rails.

Once you come to Linux/mac world there are lots of providers much cheaper than heroku like `DigitelOcean`, however `heroku` would be the easiest for a beginner I believe.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

One strategy you could try is to do the following:

Set up a VirtualBox or VMWare VM running Linux (Ubuntu would be a good candidate if you are not used to Linux).

Get your project into the VM and get the bundle install and everything working in Linux, you will probably find you need to make some changes in your Gemfile if you have anything windows specific there.

Install the Heroku tool-belt on the **Linux** VM and install to Heroku from there.

Taking the Windows / Linux transition pain on your local machine will make it much easier than Windows direct to Heroku.

Comment: sounds like the way to go..Thank you everyone for replies!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to deploy my app using Heroku. However I'm wondering if it is possible to get a a server from AWS and install required components and host on my own rather than going through Heroku or any other provider. Would that be a cheaper and feasible option?

Comment: For a small application, one where you want to only run one or two threads / dynos I have found Heroku to be cheaper, however if you want a full server then  an AWS small instance runs around $70 per month.  But given that, on my web site http://mark.stratmann.me, which is a single instance I am running rails, elasticsearch and using AWS RDS for the database and Elasticache and its a lot faster than Heroku.